# Picture folder disappeared from gallery on Huawei Ascend G6

Tags: data-recovery, photos, huawei

I have a Huawei Ascend G6, and my folder with more than 500 pictures just disappeared from my gallery. I regularly clean system with Clean Master. I did it a couple of times, downloaded DU Speed Booster and deleted it. I don't know what is the problem. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

What the problem is, is probably this:
Your clean master probably enlisted your 500 pics as *worthy* of cleaning, thus deleted them all in the process. Its just a thought, but its likely to happen.

I use ES Explorer to clean stuff on my phone, and I verify every single thing it plans to delete *everytime* I'm about to clean. You never know, it might include your *wheat among the weeds!*

Another possibility is what happens when the storage is almost full. Happened to me once, and witness a friend face same trouble. Storage was almost full, phone restarted, and everything personal info was gone, from pictures to videos to everything I put on. Perhaps one of those nightmares, but only happening to images.